# How to calculate files array in nx dep-graph?

Tags: javascript, nrwl-nx

I'm using NX v16.1.4. In these version with every build the file `node_modules/.cache/nx/nxdeps.json` is created.

The structure of this file is not identical to the file, which can be generated by nx graph and this file is not generated anymore in releases after 16.1.: Before `nodes.<app/lib>.data.files` included array with all files (and hash values).

```
"data-access-anything": {
  "name": "data-access-anything",
  "type": "lib",
  "data": {
    "name": "data-access-anything",
    "$schema": "../../../../node_modules/nx/schemas/project-schema.json",
    "sourceRoot": "libs/data-access/anything/src",
    "projectType": "library",
    "files": [ // <-- need this files array
      {
        "file": "libs/data-access/anything/.babelrc",
        "hash": "2685020516260856122"
      },
      {
        "file": "libs/data-access/anything/.eslintrc.json",
        "hash": "15754961097349354736"
      },
      // ...
    ]
  }
},
```

I used this to calculate versions of each single application by analysing the git logs. Every git commit has changed files and the file-arrays of nxdeps.json give me the information which library and which application is affected.

In the latest version this has changed. So my question is if it is possible to generate the files content manually?

Answer (score 1):

I'be been asking to get a stable API for this but haven't heard from maintainers in years unfortunately.

Someone mentioned in the original a way to do it manually though, which I believe is exactly what you're looking for, see [this comment](https://github.com/nrwl/nx/issues/3292#issuecomment-1705419999).

And don't forget to put a thumb up on the original post, hopefully at some point we'll have enough to get interest for a stable API.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But the code isn't working anymore, as `import {getProjectFileMap} from "nx/src/project-graph/build-project-graph";` is not existing in latest NX. Also it only create the hashes, not the file array.